# captcha image not shown in browser

Tags: php, image, captcha

i want to code a captcha but for some reason my picture i creat is not shown (it just show a img error symbol) 
can u tell me where my mistake is?
other ppl told me their using almost the same code and its working fine for them i just cant see my mistake.. also its my first time to try using captcha

```
<?php
session_start();

function generateCaptcha($_SESSIONNAME) {

    // Überprüfen ob der Sessionname leer ist
    if(trim($_SESSIONNAME) == '')
        die('Sessionname ist leer!');

    //schrift fuer captcha
    $font = './captcha.ttf';

    //bild erstellen auf den der captcha erscheint
    $image = imagecreate(125, 30);
    //weiß faerben des bildes
    imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

    //links 5 px Initialwert
    $left = 5;
    //alle zulaessigen Buchstaben (aehnliche rausgenommen)
    $allowed = 'aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHijJkKLmMnNpPqrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ1234578';

    //string fuer zufall code
    $string = '';

    for($i = 1;$i <= 6;$i++) // 6 Zeichen
    {
        //random nummer mit str laenge -1
        $code = $allowed{rand(0, strlen($allowed) - 1)};

        //das
        $string .= $code; // Das Zeichen an den gesamten Code anhängen
        imagettftext($image, 20, rand(-10, 10), $left + (($i == 1?5:15) * $i), 25, imagecolorallocate($image, 200, 200, 200), $font, $code);
        // Das gerade herausgesuchte Zeichen dem Bild hinzufügen
        imagettftext($image, 16, rand(-15, 15), $left + (($i == 1?5:15) * $i), 25, imagecolorallocate($image, 69, 103, 137), $font, $code);
        // Das Zeichen noch einmal hinzufügen, damit es für einen Bot nicht zu leicht lesbar ist
    }

    $_SESSION[$_SESSIONNAME] = $string; // Den Code in die Session mit dem Sessionname speichern für die Überprüfung

    header("Content-type: image/png"); // Header für ein PNG Bild setzen
    imagepng($image); // Ausgaben des Bildes
    imagedestroy($image); // Bild zerstören

}

$sessionName = 'captchacode'; // Sessionname

if(isset($_GET['captcha']))
{
    //aufruf der funltion(parameter = sessionname)
    generateCaptcha($sessionName);
    //beenden
    exit();
}

//pruefen ob form gesendet wurde
if(isset($_POST['check']))
{
    // Vergleich eingabe und code
    if($_SESSION[$sessionName] == trim($_POST['captcha']))
        echo "Richtig";
    else
        echo "Falsch";
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="captcha">
            Captcha
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" />
        <img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?captcha" alt="" />
        <button type="submit" name="check">Überprüfen</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you just go to imageurl? Probably you will see error then (what I can see in code is, that maybe you don't have GD php extension on environment when you try to run this code).
You can also try to change image url to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?captcha=1'`

Comment: ur right about the img url it shows just this error img... tried to change the url from the picture but its still the same mistake

Comment: Do you have GD library installed in your php?

Comment: wouldnt there be errors in the code if i hadnt had the GD extention and i use the expressions?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error:

- Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script above `session_start();`
- Temporarily comment out the `header("Content-type: image/png");` so the browser won't force it as an image and prevent view-source from working
- Navigate directly to script.php?captcha=1 and see the error message displayed.

Most likely you're missing GD or FreeType, or session config is borked on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Is your `$font = './captcha.ttf';` in right place ?

Comment: i thought it would make sense there.. where would u put it?

Comment: why are u asking clearity on the answer section? u have enough reps to comment